# ImportError: No module named 'google.cloud.proto.vision'

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision

**Code :**

```
from google.cloud import vision
import google.cloud.proto.vision.v1.image_annotator_pb2 as pvv 
import io

client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

def mkrl(imageStr):
    im_obj = pvv.Image(content = imageStr)
    return pvv.AnnotateImageRequest(image = im_obj, features = [{"type": "TEXT_DETECTION"}])

def getR(imageList):
    req = map(mkrl,imageList)
    response = client.batch_annotate_images(req)
    return response
```

I'm trying to extract text from an image using the google vision api. I need to send a batch of images - things were working fine but now there is this error:

> ImportError: No module named 'google.cloud.proto.vision'

Answer (score 0):

this has been solved.....

the correct way to import this is :

import google.cloud.vision_v1.proto.image_annotator_pb2 as pvv

or

from google.cloud.vision_v1.proto import image_annotator_pb2 as pvv